# Inner div's height not stretching down to 100% size

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to get the green div’s height to stretch to 100% of the size, covering the red div and can’t figure out what’s wrong. Other posts suggest setting the height of all parental divs to 100% but in this case it doesn’t do anything - neither does setting a html height to 100%.

Can someone figure out what’s wrong with my code? Thanks for the advice

```css
#sharing {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 44%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid yellow;
}

#newsletter {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 56%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}

#footer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.f1 {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.f2 {}

.clear { clear: both; }

.stretched-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<footer id="footer-wrap">
        <div class="stretched-container">
            <div id="sharing">
                <span class="f1">Share page</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div id="newsletter">
                <span class="f1">Newsletter Signup</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here height of `parent` div is `auto`, which will only increase when any one of child div i.e. `.sharing  or .newsletter` height increase which too are `100%`. Now to have height of both child div 100% as of parent then whether it's fully filled by data or not it needs to be `100%`, so for that you could display them in `table` format.

```css
#footer-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #00f;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
}

.stretched-container {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

#sharing {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 44%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  border-right: 2px solid yellow;
  display: table-cell;
}

.f1 {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.f2 {}

#newsletter {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 56%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 25px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<footer id="footer-wrap">
  <div class="stretched-container">
    <div id="sharing">
      <span class="f1">Share page</span>
      <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
    </div>
    <div id="newsletter">
      <span class="f1">Newsletter Signup</span>
      <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Welcome @user3760941 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might use a defined height on the parent div, and maybe use flexbox instead of float: left should be easier.

```css
#sharing {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 44%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid yellow;
}

#newsletter {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 56%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}

#footer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.f1 {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.f2 {}

.clear { clear: both; }

.stretched-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    /* Defined height */
    height: 350px;
    background: #f00;
    /* flexbox */
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<footer id="footer-wrap">
        <div class="stretched-container">
            <div id="sharing">
                <span class="f1">Share page</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div id="newsletter">
                <span class="f1">Newsletter Signup</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: good solution but is there any way of doing it without a fixed height? my concern is when shrinking the browser window then the divs won't be the correct size to contain the contents

Answer (score 0):

In order for the child to be a 100% - its parent's height should be defined to something other than auto.

add the following css code

```
html,#stretched-container,#footer-wrap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or set the height of each of these elements to the one you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Add display flex to the *#footer-wrap*

```css
#sharing {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 44%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid yellow;
}

#newsletter {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 56%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
}

#footer-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #00f;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    display:flex
}

.f1 {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.f2 {}

.clear { clear: both; }

.stretched-container {
    max-width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    background: #f00;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<footer id="footer-wrap">
        <div class="stretched-container">
            <div id="sharing">
                <span class="f1">Share page</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div id="newsletter">
                <span class="f1">Newsletter Signup</span>
                <span class="f2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodareLorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et delectus accommodare</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I've tried this too but nothing happens, unless the height is fixed as with victor's solution