# Child div's height not stretching to 100% of parent div's auto height

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out again why the height of the yellow `div` is not stretching to `100%` of the `height` of the parent container. Yes the parent container’s `height` is set to `auto` but the blue `div`’s `height` is also `100%` and has content inside, so I would assume the parent `div` would also increase in height to accommodate this (and you can see the pink below the yellow div, which is part of the parent). The height is there so why is the yellow `div` not stretching down to be 100% of the `height` of the parent `div`?

I’ve tried displaying the parent `div` as a `table` and children `div`s as table cells. Setting all parent elements to an 100% height suggested by other posts also do not work.

I had this problem the other day which was solved by displaying as table & table cells: [Inner div's height not stretching down to 100% size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390266/inner-divs-height-not-stretching-down-to-100-size)

Not sure why the same solution does not work since the principle is the same.

Any help and an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

```css
#software {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* HAS TO BE AUTO */
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
  width: 55%;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`height: 100%` doesn't work for children of container with `height: auto`.

#### Flexbox

Use flexbox to achieve desired layout. Flex-items (direct children of container with `display: flex`) will stretch by default, so you can remove `height: 100%`. Also flex-items don't care about `float`s. Demo:

```css
#software {
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be flex-items */
  /* flex-items will stretch by default to maximum height */
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
  width: 55%;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

#### Table layout

You can achieve the same using table layout (`display: table` for container and `display: table-cell` for children). This approach has the best browser support. Demo:

```css
#software {
  display: table;

  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  display: table-cell;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
  width: 55%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

#### [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

You can make you `#software` a container and specify column width using CSS  `grid-template-columns` property (move column definition to container). Demo:

```css
#software {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 55%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: left;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

For this to work in IE10+/Edge you just need to specify old syntax properties and manual alignment of grid items (By default IE/Edge will stack all grid items in first cell). Demo:

```css
#software {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 45% 55%;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 55%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: left;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
  /* manual positioning for IE/Edge */
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Great to see all the various methods. I was so close but just didn't remove the float after displaying as tables and table-cells. Thanks!

Comment: @Vadim please see this fiddle: jsfiddle.net/hasugamer/mpjboLsd/57/. Setting a height of 100% on a child of type **div** which has a parent with height auto (its generated based on children) actually does seem to work (with some relative/absolute positioning). However, doing the same for a child of type **table** doesn't ? Could you please explain why this is? or point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @George! Actually using absolute positioning in case you provided is hacky layout. I've provided several valid ways. I strongly recommend you not to use absolute positioning unless you really need it (when you intentionally need overlapping etc).

Comment: Hello @VadimOvchinnikov thanks for the reply! Yeah so this is purely for educational purposes. I don't intend to use such techniques in production code. So could you please explain why, in my case, relative hight (50%) only works for the **div** and not the **table** in the case that the parent has a height of `auto` or where could I go and read about it? Thanks!

Comment: @George I'm not sure it's good idea to not use `table` other way than they are designed for. If you could you any apply arbitrary `position` on table cells then it would become not a table anymore. But if you are very curious you can try to ask new question here.

Answer (score 2):

Remove floats, use `display: table` on parent and `display: table-cell` on child `divs`.

```css
#software {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* HAS TO BE AUTO */
  background: pink;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: table;
}

#software-text {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

#software-image {
  background: yellow;
  width: 55%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.sections {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
  <h1>Products</h1>
  <article id="software">
    <div id="software-text">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap
      into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentiall also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
      unchanged when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
    <div id="software-image">background image goes inside this yellow div &amp; needs to stretch to 100% height</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex;` to id `#software`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ctewmp0/1/

Answer (score 1):

To do that, one way can be put to id="software" display:table and the childs id="software-text" and id="software-image" display:table-cell , and you have to remove float attribute for this layers

Here you have

https://fiddle.jshell.net/02gzwmbj/