# table with height 100% doesn't fit parent size

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've a table inside a div inside the main.
all of this have width = 100% but when i make the window smaller just the div ant the main gets smaller but the table dosent resize. all other elements below the table change position and size and starts lay over it. the table has 25 records and if the window is full-size everything matches perfect.
The div im talkin about has the id home

The html:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Panel | Please Login</title>
    <link href='../css/admin.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60"> 
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div id='container'>
        <img src="../img/ipw_quer_rgb.jpg" alt="IPW Logo" id="logo" width="15%">
        <header>

            <ul id='menu'>
            <div id="links">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/stmanager.html">Schüler verwalten</a></li>
                <li><a href="/html/history.html">History</a></li>
            </div>  
            </ul>

        </header>

            <div id="home">
                <h2 id="date"></h2>
                <table id="table">
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">

                        <select id="select">
                          <option value="Nothing">Nichts ausgewählt</option>
                          <option value="Extern">Extern</option>
                          <option value="Termin">Termin</option>
                          <option value="Schule">Schule</option>
                        </select>   

            </div>

            <div id="legend" class="legend">
                        <svg width="10" height="10">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style="fill:#D3D3D3;" />
                        </svg>
                        <a>Extern</a>
                        <br>
                        <svg width="10" height="10">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style="fill:#FFAEB9;" />
                        </svg>
                        <a>Termin</a>
                        <br>
                        <svg width="10" height="10">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style="fill:#FFFF00;" />
                        </svg>
                        <a>Schule</a>
                        <br>
                        <svg width="10" height="10">
                        <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" style="fill:#00FF00;" />
                        </svg>
                        <a>Visiert</a>
                        <br>
                        <button id="edit">Editieren</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

the css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}




main{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


label{
    font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
html, body{
    background-color: #006975;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h3{
    margin-right:50%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% -50px);
}

ul {
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #006975;
}

li {
  width:25%;
  float: left;
}
h1{
    text-align:center;
}


li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  border-left: 2px solid #fff;
   border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    color: #006975;
    background-color: #fff;
}

button:hover{

    color:#fff;
    background-color:#84afb8;
}


#container{
    position:absolute;
    margin: 4% 4% 4% 4%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #fff;
}


#home{
    height:60%;
}

#dropdown{
    width:100%;
    height:2%;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.cell {
    height: 4%;
    width:10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.cell.on {
height: 4%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
.cell.les {
height: 4%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}

.cell.term {
height: 4%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #FFAEB9;
}
.cell.ext{
height: 4%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}

.cell.spacer {
height: 4%;
    width: 10%;
    background-color:white;
}

.name {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

if you also need the javascript please ask

**EDIT:**
javascript:

```
getDataUser('logGLAUSB');

var names = ["Zebra","Benj", "Nico", "Timon","Miro", "Leo"];
var longpresstimer = null;

getData();
window.addEventListener('click', function(){
});


window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    var clickcount = 0;
    var singleClickTimer;
    document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

            clickcount++;
            if(clickcount==1){
                if(event.target.tagName != "INPUT" && event.target.classList != 'cell spacer'){
                    singleClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                        clickcount = 0;
                        var cell = event.target;
                        var selected = getSelected();
                        if(selected == 3){
                            cell.classList.remove("ext");
                            cell.classList.remove("term");
                            cell.classList.remove("les");
                            cell.classList.add("on");
                        }else{
                            cell.classList.remove("ext");
                            cell.classList.remove("term");
                            cell.classList.remove("les");
                            cell.classList.remove("on");
                            switch(selected){
                                case 0: cell.classList.add("ext"); break;
                                case 1: cell.classList.add("les"); break;
                                case 2: cell.classList.add("term"); break;
                            }
                        }
                        var x = "get";
                        x += getString(event.target.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML);
                        getData(x);

                    }, 300);
                }
            }else if (clickcount == 2){
                if(event.target.classList != "name"){
                    clearTimeout(singleClickTimer);
                    clickcount = 0;
                    toInput(event.target);
                }
        }
    });



    });


    document.getElementById("edit").addEventListener('click', function(){
        var legend = document.getElementById("legend");
        var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
        var select = document.getElementById('select');

            legend.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            dropdown.style.visibility = 'visible';
            var button = document.createElement('button');
            button.innerHTML= "Fertig";
            dropdown.appendChild(button);
            button.onclick = function(){
                legend.style.visibility = 'visible';
                dropdown.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                dropdown.removeChild(button);
                select.value = "Nothing";

            }


    });


    function reset(){
    var rows = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('row'));
                var table = document.getElementById('table');
                rows.forEach(function (row){
                    var cells = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('cell'));
                    for(var i = 0;i< cells.length;i++){
                    var cell = cells[i]
                        cell.classList.remove('on');
                        cell.classList.remove('les');
                        cell.classList.remove('term');  
                        cell.classList.remove('ext');   
                    }

                }); 
                var x = "rep";
                x += getResetString();
                getData(x);
    }

        function clearSelection() {
            if(document.selection && document.selection.empty) {
                document.selection.empty();
            } else if(window.getSelection) {
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
            }
        }

        function getData(str) {
            var requestURL = "http://adopraesenz.ipwin.ch/data/students.php?q=" +str;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {           
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    loadJson(request);
                }
            };
            request.open("GET", requestURL, true);
            request.send();
        }
        function getDataHistory(str) {
            var requestURL = "http://adopraesenz.ipwin.ch/data/history.php?q=" +str;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {           
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    if(request.responseText != ""){
                        loadDate(request);      
                    }
                }
            };
            request.open("GET", requestURL, true);
            request.send();
        }
        function getDataUser(str){
            var requestURL = "http://adopraesenz.ipwin.ch/data/login.php?q=" +str;
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {           
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
                    if(request.responseText != ""){
                        loadDate(request);      
                    }                           }
            };
            request.open("GET", requestURL, true);
            request.send();
        }


        function getSelected(cell) {
            var value = document.getElementById("select").value;
            switch(value){
                case "Extern": return 0; break;
                case "Schule": return 1; break;
                case "Termin": return 2; break;
                default: return 3;
            }
        }


        function loadDate(request){
                var newDate = new Date();
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() -1);
                newDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var days = request.responseText.split(".");
                var oldDate = new Date(days[1]+"."+days[0]+"."+days[2]);

                if(newDate > oldDate){
                    var date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
                    var dd = date.getDate();
                    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
                    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
                    if(dd < 10) {
                        dd = '0' +dd;
                    }
                    if(mm < 10) {
                        mm = '0' +mm;
                    }
                    var yesterday = dd+"."+mm+"."+yyyy;
                    getDataHistory('add' + yesterday);
                    reset();
                }

                newDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString('de-CH', {
                    weekday: 'long',
                    day: '2-digit',
                    month: '2-digit',
                    year: 'numeric'
                });


                document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = newDate;

        }
        getDataHistory('new');

        function loadJson(request){
            createTable(request.responseText);
        }


        function createHeader(array){

            var header = document.createElement("thead");
            var hRow = document.createElement('tr');
            hRow.classList.add('header');
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var th = document.createElement('th');
                div.innerHTML = array[i];
                th.appendChild(div);
                hRow.appendChild(th);
            }
            header.appendChild(hRow);
            return header;
        }


        function createTable(json){ 

            var obj = JSON.parse(json);
            var oldBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            console.log(oldBody);
            var oldHeader = document.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
            var body = document.createElement('tbody');
            var header = createHeader(["Name","09:00 – 09:45","10:15 – 11:00","11:00 – 11:45"," ","14:00 – 14:45","15:00 - 15:45","16:00 – 16:45"]);
            for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
                    var row = addRow(obj[j],body);
                    row.classList.add('row');   
            }
            console.log(body);
            replaceTable(body, oldBody, header ,oldHeader);

            if(obj.length > 25){
                var view = document.getElementById('home');
                view.setAttribute("style", "overflow-y:scroll");
            }
        }
        function toInput(cell){
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            setTimeout(function() { input.focus(); }, 200);
            cell.appendChild(input);

            window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
                if(e.keyCode == '13'){
                    var text = input.value;
                    if(input.parentNode != null){
                        input.parentNode.removeChild(input);
                    }
                    cell.innerHTML = text;
                    getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML));
                }
            }, false);

        }

        function replaceTable(body, oldBody, header, oldHeader){
            if(typeof oldHeader == 'undefined'){
                    table.appendChild(header);
            }else if(oldHeader.parentNode == table){
                table.replaceChild(header, oldHeader);
            }else{
                table.appendChild(header);
            }


            if(typeof oldBody == 'undefined'){
                    table.appendChild(body);
            }else if(oldBody.parentNode == table){
                    table.removeChild(oldBody);
                    table.appendChild(body);
                    //table.replaceChild(body, oldBody);
            }else{
                table.appendChild(body);
            }

        }

        function addRow(val,body) {

            var rest = val.split(";");
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for( var i = 0; i < 8; i++){

                if(i==0){
                    var name = rest[0];
                    addCell(tr, null,name);
                }else{
                    var value = rest[i];
                    addCell(tr, value, name);
                }

            }
        body.appendChild(tr);               
        return tr;
        }
        function addCell(tr, val, name) {


            var name;
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            var value = "get";
            if(val == null){
                var input = document.createElement('label');
                cell.classList.add("name")
                input.innerHTML = name;
                input.readOnly = true;
                cell.appendChild(input);
            }else{ 
                cell = document.createElement('td');
                cell.classList.add('cell');
                var content = val.split(":");
                switch(content[0]){
                    case '0': cell.classList.add('ext'); break;
                    case '1': cell.classList.add('les'); break;
                    case '2': cell.classList.add('term'); break;
                    case '3': cell.classList.add('on'); break;
                    case '4': cell.classList.add('spacer'); break;
                }

                if(val.length > 1){
                    cell.innerHTML = content[1];
                }


            }
            tr.appendChild(cell);
        }


        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (!event.target.matches('.dropA')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
              if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
              }
            }
          }
        }

        function getString(name){
        var x = "";
        var names = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
        var values = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
            for(var i = 0;i<names.length;i++){
                if(names[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML == name){

                    x+= names[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML + ";";
                    for(var j = (7 * i); j < (7 * i) + 7 ; j++){
                            switch(""+values[j].classList){
                                case 'cell':        x += "0"; break;
                                case 'cell ext':    x += "0"; break;
                                case 'cell les':    x += "1"; break;
                                case 'cell term':   x += "2"; break;
                                case 'cell on':     x += "3"; break;
                                case 'cell spacer': x += "4"; break;
                        }
                        if(values[j].innerHTML != "" && values[j].innerHTML != null){
                            x+= ":" + values[j].innerHTML
                        }
                        x += ";";
                    }

                }
            }   
        return x;
    }




    function getResetString(){
        var names = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
        var x = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            x += names[i].value +";";
            for (var j = 0; j < 7 ; j++){
                if(j == 3){
                    x += "4";
                }else{
                    x += "0";
                }
            x += ";";
            }
            if(i < names.length-1){
                x+="|";
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the code that is inside your table? I see the css classes but no html with them. The issue is likely what is in the table, not the table itself.

Comment: Please include all your code so that the problem can be diagnosed and then possibly solved.

Comment: i've made an edit

Comment: Did you mean to put this style on the table? You are missing a space before the 50: height:calc(100% - 50px);

Comment: still dosent work even with the space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Child div's height not stretching to 100% of parent div's auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415719/child-divs-height-not-stretching-to-100-of-parent-divs-auto-height)

Comment: @Rob i've tried to set display to table but nothing happened

Comment: Your doctype is incorrect. Should be: `<!DOCTYPE html>` Note the exclamation point.

Comment: `table` height cannot be controlled. It's controlled *only by its content*.

Comment: can i add a dynamical scrollbar based on window size?

Answer (score 1):

it seems a tiny problem. on your css, you have to add an space on the `calc` statement:

`height:calc(100% - 50px);`

I was able to make it work in here

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-http-ty85k

Comment: i've allready added this space but nothing happend and here https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-http-ty85k you don't have content inside the table the problem only appears when i have content in the table

Comment: Can you provide more data? Because i've put a `<tr><td>content</td></tr>` inside my example. would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: table;` to #container
and add:

```
#legend {
    display: table-row;
}
```

This should work, but I think you should refactor (simplify) the whole page and styles.